# How to transfer object to another file and send it to database using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs

I export objects from a file. but how can I get that value from another file and  make that objects as setValue and send it to mongoDB?

Comment: Please show us an example of what you mean, we cannot really help you from what you described

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.